# Jira Vs Google Docs for Sprint (Agile)

Tags: documentation, agile, jira, scrum

Can someone let me know the pros and cons or using Jira and/or Google docs for Agile sprints?
We are team of 8 developers and planning to switch to either Jira or google docs.

We currently use white board for sprint stories....

Thanks

Comment: Look at trello.com you can create cards and lists which work like stories in SCRUM

Answer (score 3):

To be honest it would be like comparing one of the old cellphones to the new smartphone- it's true you could use both to make a call, but on a smartphone you could do so much more.. the list of Jira's pros is long, and i don't think that the Google docs have any major pros over Jira, except it's free. 
You can try jira for free to evaluate it, just get it from http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/overview.

If you are using it for agile planing, be aware that Jira itself is lacking many of the agile dearly needed properties, but they offer an expansion called green-hopper which add a lot of power and help with the agile management.